# Website stopped working properly after pointing to a new SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, iis, sql-server-2012, iis-8

We had our webserver (IIS) running our website (ASP.NET) working perfectly for a week. We pointed to a new SQL Server by changing the ip address on our Web.Config file. The website still works fine, but it starts giving timeouts due to "Max connection pool size reached" errors.

How can changing to a new SQL SERVER change our IIS behaviour about the pool size?

Comment: Is the new sql server slower than the old one or Is your app under more load? Also are you sure your app is properly disposing of connections?

Comment: The new one is a 2012, the old one was a 2005. That's the difference. THe hardware is far better.

Comment: Are the servers physically close to each other - ie any additional latency?

Answer (score 0):

Check the pool size of the sql server the application is connected to, by checking sql server / db settings provided by the Hosting Server.

Or set a pool size manually in the connection string by adding 
Max Pool Size=200; to the connection string.

Comment: I didnt change my iis only pointed yo a new sql server. So why should i modify the pool size?

Comment: Well in that case you should the connections whether they are properly closed or not.

Comment: Also check this url if it can help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling